# Implementing static ID generator in java

Tags: java, selenium, static, generator, zk

I found this open source Static ID Generator java code in https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/master/zk/src/org/zkoss/zk/ui/impl/StaticIdGenerator.java

Mu question is, how do I try it? After having a static id generator and adding the configurations in the zk.xml, what's next? How will I be able to run it and get the generated ids?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to "run it". If you specify a custom ID generator in the configuration (zk.xml), the zk application you run will use it to automatically create a new ID for every widget on the client. Using a static ID generator just makes sure that the IDs are always created in the same sequence, the default one is somewhat random.

You can see the IDs in the browser (in the developer console, the html tree will show you the "id" attributes of certain elements). You can also access them by `Component.getUuid()`.

By the way, there is also a built-in implementation of a static ID generator: `org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.StaticIdGenerator`. Read [zk's testing tipps](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Testing/Testing_Tips#Approach_2:_Implement_ID_Generator), they mention it there and also explain why you would use it.