# ERROR Jmeter: component not found (ZKOSS)

Tags: jmeter, zk

Ive been done recording on JMeter, the transaction consist of fill a form and save the data.
While recording it runs smoothly.
But when I run the sampling, on clicking save button sampling the response was Component (uuid) was not found. and that cause the rest sampling return an error

Comment: Have you specified a static ID generator in your zk.xml (tag `id-generator-class`)? You could read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44717720/7653073) on another question for info on that.

Comment: @MalteHartwig I already had, but still doesnt work

Comment: Can you verify that the IDs were the same during recording and running via the element view in the browser? If not, how are the elements created? Is the page layout constant or does it depend on dynamic data?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's a correlation issue, you can see [example](https://moduscreate.com/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/) or if you need to add UUID value you can use [UUID function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) .

> `${UUID()}` will return UUIDs with this format :
>   c69e0dd1-ac6b-4f2b-8d59-5d4e8743eecd

Answer (score 0):

Zk creates uniques id's componentes on every request, this means that a recording form is not valid for consecutive requests with same id's.
The complete reference for the use of this testing tools with Zk is on:

[ZK Testing Tips](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Testing/Testing_Tips)